# MySQL Error 3033 Binary geometry function mbrintersects given two geometries of different srids: 900913 and 3857, which should have been identical

Tags: mysql, spatial

I get this error message when trying to find geometries in MySQL 5.7 that intersects:

```
General error: 3033 Binary geometry function mbrintersects given two geometries of different srids: 900913 and 3857, which should have been identical.
```

Isn't it possible to intersect two geometries that have different srid? Or better: How could I solve this?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?